# Docker can't copy files from outsite of Dockerfile's folder

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I can't copy file from outsite of dockerfile's folder.
I'm getting error from docker-compose build:

```
failed to compute cache key: failed to walk /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount196528245/target: lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount196528245/target: no such file or directory
ERROR: Service 'discovery' failed to build : Build failed
```

There is the folder structure

```
discovery
  -docker
     Dockerfile
  -target
     discovery.jar
```

This is Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:11
ARG JAR_FILE=../target/discovery.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

and this is my docker-compose file

```
services:
discovery:
    build: ./discovery/docker
    ports:
      - 8761:8761
```

Thank in adance for help.

Answer (score 2):

This is by design.

The Docker build context (a tarball sent to the Docker daemon along with the instructions in the Dockerfile) is computed from the directory you run `docker build` in.

You'll need to do

```
$ docker build -f docker/Dockerfile
```

within `discovery`, with

```
ARG JAR_FILE=./target/discovery.jar
```

(not `..`) (or pass the corresponding `--build-arg`).

Comment: @AKK  but I can't go out from the docker folder to build app

Comment: Then you're going to have a hard time building your app, since this is how Docker works.

Answer (score 2):

AS already pointed out in AKX answer, you cannot move outside the context (upwards). I just want to show that can build your app by providing the right parameters. Since you state that, you can't go out of the docker folder.

```yaml
discovery:
  build:
    context: discovery
    Dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
    args:
      JAR_FILE: target/discovery.jar
```

The key is to use the parent directory *discovery* as context, but use the Dockerfile from the child directory *docker*. Note that this is relative to the build context when using compose.